# mathematica not specifying indeterminate cases in integrals/simplifications

Tags: symbolic

I think this is undesirable behavior in a new version.

```
Integrate[Cos[l*θ]*Sin[lp*θ]*Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}]
```

Will return the formula:

```
1/4 (Sin[(l - lp) π]/(-1 + l - lp) + Sin[(1 + l - lp) π]/(
   1 + l - lp) - (2 Sin[(l + lp) π])/((-1 + l + lp) (1 + l + lp)))
```

Which is valid when |l-lp| != 1, and is otherwise indeterminate. For example `Integrate[ Cos[2 θ] Sin[3 θ] *Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}]` is (correctly) pi/4 Whereas if you simplify the previous answer assuming l,lp are integers you will get zero (which is just wrong)

Does anyone know how to avoid this behavior? I have clear memories of these types of integrals being treated properly in previous versions.

Comment: The option `GenerateConditions -> True` is meant for this purpose but it does not seem to have any effect here, apart from triggering some simplification.  10.4.1 behaves the same as 11.0.1.

Comment: This is normal and common behaviour for all computer algebra systems.  It's essentially the same as `Integrate[Cos[a x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`, where you might ask what about $a=0$.  The result may not be valid for certain specific values of the parameters. This does not usually happen when the result is only valid for a *range* of parameter values: in that case it will usually return a `ConditionalExpression.`  Conditions aren't usually generated for single values.  I'll note that the result, as written, is valid in the limit of `lp -> l`, and also that it is not true that it simplifies to zero.

Comment: I suppose another reason that a `ConditionalExpression` is not generated is that the answer is correct even when its denominator vanishes, as can be seen from `Limit[%, #] & /@ Solve[Denominator[%] == 0, l]`, where `%` here represents the solution of the integral, simplified to have a common denominator.

Comment: You can run `Assuming[{l - lp == 1}, 
 Integrate[
  Cos[l*\[Theta]]*Sin[lp*\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 
   0, \[Pi]}]]` and `Assuming[{l - lp != 1}, 
 Integrate[
  Cos[l*\[Theta]]*Sin[lp*\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 
   0, \[Pi]}]]` to differentiate the two explicitly.

Comment: @Szabolcs - I believe that he meant "assuming l, lp are integers" rather than "assuming l, lp are reals"

Comment: Wow, I'm overwhelmed by the very rapid and insightful comments. It is unfortunate though that it doesn't generate a conditional expression... C'est la vie a suppose, no real substitute for the 'old mathematics degree.

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of belaboring my comment above, I would assert that `Integrate` is producing a correct answer.  To see that this is so, obtain the solution in a form that explicitly shows the apparent singularities.

```
s = Simplify@Together@Integrate[Cos[l*θ]*Sin[lp*θ]*Sin[θ], {θ, 0, π}]
(* (2 l lp Cos[lp π] Sin[l π] - (-1 + l^2 + lp^2) Cos[l π] Sin[lp π])
   /((-1 + l - lp) (1 + l - lp) (-1 + l + lp) (1 + l + lp)) *)
```

The four singularities are removable in the sense that the numerator and denominator vanish together and have a finite limit.

```
Limit[s, #] & /@ Solve[Denominator[s] == 0, l]
(* {{(-2 lp (1 + lp) π + Sin[2 lp π])/(8 lp (1 + lp))}, 
    {( 2 (-1 + lp) lp π + Sin[2 lp π])/(8 (-1 + lp) lp)}, 
    {( 2 (-1 + lp) lp π + Sin[2 lp π])/(8 (-1 + lp) lp)}, 
    {(-2 lp (1 + lp) π + Sin[2 lp π])/(8 lp (1 + lp))}} *)
```

Plotting the solution also shows that it is well-behaved everywhere.

```
Plot3D[s, {l, -2, 2}, {lp, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

The white curves, indicating where the numerator and denominator together vanish, can be removed with the option `Exclusions -> None`, if desired.  Of course, `Limit` must be used when performing numerical calculations using `s` at the locations of the removable singularities.

Comment: Nice explanation and thanks for belaboring.